# How do I receive the payment?

Tags: bitcoind

And the payment request, if i have not been paid.
Do what it is to have not come still pay?
How do I receive the payment?

Comment: This question is unintelligible. If someone understands it, please feel free to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have not received the Bitcoin payment you are expecting, contact the sender and ask for the transaction ID.

You can copy the transaction ID into a blockchain explorer like blockchain.info or https://www.blocktrail.com/ to track the payment. If you cannot see the transaction ID, the send never sucessfully broadcast the transaction to the Bitcoin network.

If you can see the payment but it has not confirmed you will be able to tell if the problem is related to the transaction fee being too low, the BTC being sent to the wrong address or something else.

Comment: The wallet Is the same even in the case of Bitcoin core?
It is being read  now wallet.

Comment: Why pay waiting a long time?

Comment: @Hiro any wallet is fine for checking the status of your transaction. Just making the blockchain is fully synced.